# Activating Bottom AppBar from Code behind in WinRT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Does anyone know of a way to activate the bottom AppBar from code-behind when we select a tile? I found this, but I could not find a C# equivalent. I've browsed around a bunch of samples but no luck

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229676.aspx

Comment: There is a flag called IsOpen, which means it should be opened, not activated. no suporting functions though. how does the start page handle this for selected objects?

Comment: the IsOpen flag is not read-only. setting that works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting IsOpen to true in XAML should be enough to make it visible when the page opens. If you want to set focus on the AppBar - it can only be done on a button click or key press event by calling appBar.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic).

Answer (score 5):

i suppose you want to always show the app bar when you select a tile.

you can always set IsOpen and isSticky to true from code-behind from the tile event-handler